# What should be done about the code tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tagwiki

### Update

<sup>This question was previously titled "What is the code tag?".</sup>

As it was before, my question wasn't super useful. Since it looks like there isn't necessarily an overwhelming rhyme or reason to the tag (see [Paul's comment](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4646/what-is-the-code-tag#comment15348_4646)), the question should more appropriately be "what should be done about the [code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code) tag?".

---

### Question as it was before

What is the [code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code) tag? It has no wiki summary, and I can't really seem to find any apparent pattern among all of the questions that have been tagged with [code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code), at least not immediately.

Comment: It also has no currently approved tag synonyms. A look through the related tags list shows that it's most often used for code listings and other verbatim content, but that use is far from overwhelming.

Comment: @PaulGessler thanks for taking a closer look. I've made a suggestion (in the form of an answer) as to what we might do about the tag.

Answer (score 4):

<sup>Here is on suggestion. Feel free to suggest others in the answers section, if you have alternative suggestions. And then perhaps after a while we can decide on one course of action.</sup>

---

Based on Paul's inspection of the questions that are tagged as [code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code), it seems that it might be appropriate to make the tag about typesetting code for (other) programming languages.

If everyone likes this idea, then we should add that to the wiki summary and untag the questions that don't fit the category. (Doing this slowly over time, of course, so as not to bump everything to the top of the active questions list.)

Comments/edits amending this suggestion are more than welcome! Or, again, feel free to suggest an alternative!

Comment: The problem is, in my point of view, that `code` is a vary vague term. Anyway, I support your suggestion

Comment: Whatever we do, I believe that the tag should get blacklisted in the end. No matter how hard you try to explain its purpose in the excerpt, people will misuse it.

Comment: @tohecz Perhaps it could also be renamed? Maybe it could be something like `typesetting-code`.

Comment: Looking at the highest voted questions with this tag shows that this is a poor fit, they are about writing tex/latex itself, so these would need to be retagged.